# pip installing ipython with readline on OSX Lion

Tags: readline, ipython, pip, osx-lion

What is required to get ipython fully functional on OSX Lion?   I'm trying to get ipython with readline working and having no success.

My approach:

(inside a virtual environment)

`pip install ipython   # runs, but only slightly useful because can't indent blocks`
`pip install readline`

The second completes with warnings and eventually says "Successfully installed readline"
But I'm still left without the ability to indent blocks and going back in the command history leads to garbled terminal output.

I suspect these warnings are critical, but I'm at a loss about what to do about them.

*ld: warning: ignoring file readline/libreadline.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)*

*ld: warning: ignoring file readline/libhistory.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)*

(I've spent the morning googling the errors, to no avail)

tia,

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've had the same issue and for some reason only the version of readline installed via `easy_install readline` works fine.

Comment: Thank you.   Using easy_install readline did indeed fix my immediate problem.   I am curious about why it didn't work with pip install.   I'm going to leave this question open for a little longer to see if anyone can answer that before accepting this as the answer.   Thanks again!

Comment: @goliher: It's something to do with where they put them on your pythonpath. I think pip puts it after the system version, whereas easy_install puts it before.

Comment: I found that putting my virtualenv lib at the start of my PYTHONPATH let me pip install ipython and deadline and work ok.  Like so..   export PYTHONPATH=/Users/dgolliher/.virtualenvs/play-ipython/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

Comment: FWIW, I noticed that easy_install downloads and installs readline binaries, whereas pip downloads readline source and builds the package. That would explain the mystery of why one will work, while the other will not. https://gist.github.com/kprav33n/9521565

Answer (score 7):

1) Upgraded to latest Mac OS X dev tools

2) Installed [Distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/)

3) pip install ipython

4) pip install readline

Thanks to [this article](http://www.sherman.ca/archives/2011/07/25/lion-broken-python-easy_install/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm glad I was able to avoid easy_install. I'm not sure why, but on Lion, when I tried `pip install readline` _after_ `pip install ipython` in my virtualenv it failed. So I closed out my terminal, activated my virtualenv, and ran it again, and it worked. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I think it's because readline is *required* by ipython. So you need to install readline first.

Comment: What is the motivation for avoiding easy_install?  It simply works better than pip for binary packages like readline.  For instance, you do not need OSX dev tools (or any compiler) to use `easy_install readline`.  It's two steps on a perfectly fresh OS X: 1. install distribute; 2. `easy_install readline ipython`.

Comment: XCode 4.5.2 doesn't install command-line tools by default.  If you haven't already, go to XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components  and install Command Line Tools.